# after insert trigger showing error in mysql while creating trigger- Unknown column 'IMEI' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

i want to create a trigger while inserting a new row it should update a row in a trigger table - table 2, if the same IMEI is available, if the IMEI is not available in trigger table (table2) then it should insert a new row in the trigger table table2. i have created the trigger but when im inserting a new row in the table1 im getting error -unknown column

> INSERT INTO `vtsdb`.`table1` (`Id`, `IMEI`, `dataframeId`) VALUES
>   ('22', '456', '4455') 1054: Unknown column 'IMEI' in 'field list'

trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
    create TRIGGER trigger_livedata
    AFTER INSERT ON `table1`
    FOR EACH ROW
    begin 
     IF (NEW.IMEI = IMEI) THEN
            UPDATE table2 SET IMEI = NEW.IMEI,dataframeId=NEW.dataframeId  where IMEI = NEW.IMEI;
     ELSE    
            INSERT INTO table2(IMEI,dataframeId) VALUES (NEW.IMEI,NEW.dataframeId);
    END IF;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Error - 
ERROR 1054: 1054: Unknown column 'IMEI' in 'field list'
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m17Gq.png)

table1 schema

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IMEI` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `dataframeId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IMEI` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `dataframeId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

sample data of table1

```
Id, IMEI, dataframeId
'20', '123', '2233'
'21', '456', '4455'

table2
Id, IMEI, dataframeId
```

Comment: I suspect you should have an existence check to decide whether to insert or update. (i feel I am repeating mysql see comment to your post may 4)

Comment: yes that i have to check , but i don't how to check the existence of that record.can u guide how to add that logic to decide whether i need to perform update or insert.
@P.Salmon in the previous question i did not gave the schema and sample data. here i provided sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for existence and insert or update

```
if not exists (select 1 from table2 where table2.imei = new.emei) then 
   INSERT INTO table2(IMEI,dataframeId) VALUES (NEW.IMEI,NEW.dataframeId);
else
   UPDATE table2 SET IMEI = NEW.IMEI,dataframeId=NEW.dataframeId  where IMEI = NEW.IMEI;
END IF;
```

or if you prefer

```
if exists (select 1 from table2 where table2.imei = new.emei) then 
  UPDATE table2 SET IMEI = NEW.IMEI,dataframeId=NEW.dataframeId  where IMEI = NEW.IMEI;
else
  INSERT INTO table2(IMEI,dataframeId) VALUES (NEW.IMEI,NEW.dataframeId);
END IF;
```